# TypeScript defining recursive object with known end?

Tags: json, typescript, types, interface

first time posting a question.

So my problem is that I want to define an object for storing strings in different languages. This needs to be flexible so the best I've come up with is a nested object structure, but I want the last object to be a specific type or interface.

At first I tried:

```
interface Text {
  [key: string | number]: ComponentText | Language;
}

interface Language {
  [key: string]: string;
}

text: Text = {
  title: {
    en: "English text",
    sv: "Swedish text",
    fr: "French Text",
    es: "Spanish Text",
  }
  paragraph: {
    subText: {
      en: "English text",
      sv: "Swedish text",
      fr: "French Text",
      es: "Spanish Text",
    }
  }
}

// getCurrLang(s: any) handles getting the correct language string or throws an error when "s" isn't "Language".
```

But I'm getting errors when I try to retreive the `getCurrLang(text['paragraph']['subText'])` saying:

`Argument of type 'string | Text | Language' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Text | Language'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Text | Language'.`

This is something I've come up with that I thought would solve the problem, but unless the key value can contain the same as "language" this doesn't work and solves nothing:

```
type LangCode = 'en' | 'sv' | 'fr' | 'es';

interface Text {
  [key: string]: ComponentText | Array<ComponentText>;
  language?: Language;
}

type Language = {
  [key in LangCode]: string;
};
```

Is there a way to define this type of structure or something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the way we tried to  the nested objects.
Even with the type definition from [@David Culberth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72967782/19533082) TypeScript requires the use of type narrowing when it is of a union type `ComponentText | TextTranslation`

And can not be retrieved by a simple `getCurrLang(text['paragraph']['subText'])`

To fix this I extended the `getCurrLang(s: any)` as such:

```
public getLangString(
  s: ComponentText | TextTranslation,
  selector?: Array<string>
): string {
  if (this.isTextTranslation(s)) {
    return s[this.getLanguage()];
  } else if (this.isComponentText(s) && selector) {
    return this.getLangString(
      s[selector[0]],
      selector.length > 1 ? selector.slice(1) : undefined
    );
  }

  return 'error: ' + s + 'is not of type TextTranslation or ComponentText';
}
```

So the retrieving now looks like this `getLangString(text, ['paragraph', 'subText'])`

Answer (score 0):

I broke this structure into two separate ideas: a set of translations for a specific text element (the `TextTranslation`), and a structure to store these dynamically like you specified for use in a component (`ComponentText`).

```
type LangCode = 'en' | 'sv' | 'fr' | 'es';

type TextTranslation = {
  [key in LangCode]: string;
};

interface ComponentText {
  [key: string | number]: ComponentText | TextTranslation;
}


let text: ComponentText = {
  title: {
    en: "English text",
    sv: "Swedish text",
    fr: "French Text",
    es: "Spanish Text",
  },
  paragraph: {
    subText: {
      en: "English text",
      sv: "Swedish text",
      fr: "French Text",
      es: "Spanish Text",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying to extract the TextTranslation object with `text['paragraph']['subText']` getting error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"subText"' can't be used to index type 'ComponentText | TextTranslation'.
  Property 'subText' does not exist on type 'ComponentText | TextTranslation'.`

But I'm starting to think this is mostly because the type isn't set. It is used in an Angular html template like this: `{{ getCurrLang(text['paragraph']['subText']) }}`
Since the object type of `text['paragraph']` isn't known?